# Cant drop column named condition

Tags: mysql

I have a column named condition VARCHAR(255) in one of my tables. I would like to drop the column from the table and seems like it doesn't work.
I tried

```
alter table vehicle_new_full drop column condition;
```

It gives me this error.

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition hello varchar(255)' at line 1
```

Tried altering the column name which also doesn't work.I was able to drop other columns from the tables but not this one and this doesn't have any constraints as well. Any ideas?

Structure of tables

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| styleId          | bigint(11)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| year             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| make             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| model            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| trim             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| condition        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| vehicleStyle     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| engineCylinder   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| engineFuelType   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| drivenWheels     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| transmissionType | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numberOfDoors    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
alter table vehicle_new_full drop column `condition`;
```

CONDITION is a reserved keyword for mysql.

Reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: post the design of you table

Comment: @DylanSu alter table vehicle_new_full drop column 'condition';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''condition'' at line 1

Comment: @upagna copy my SQL statement. You are running a different one.

Comment: @DylanSu Thanks Dylan. It worked. I thought both the statements were the same .

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL ALTER TABLE command looks different than what MySQL receive. You said you drop `condition` field but MySQl reported  `syntax to use near 'condition hello varchar(255)'`. Maybe there's part of your code that accidentally add this `hello varchar(255)` line to your SQL. See your query log to better understand.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to use any mysql reserved words when declaring column name as the name itself "reserved".

Put additional character if you still want to use the reserved word such as condition1, conditions, etc..